# Verifying a set being a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n$ be a fixed natural number. Verify that the set $n\mathbb{Z}=\{nk\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

**Solution**

Suppose we want to show that $n\cdot\mathbb{Z}=\{n\cdot k\mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

First, we show closure:

Given $l,l'\in n\cdot\mathbb{Z}$, we have that:
$l = n\cdot t$, $l'=n\cdot t'$ for some integers $t,t'$.

So $l+l'$=n$\cdot$$t$ + n$\cdot$$t'$ = n($t + t'$).

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group and closed under addition, $t + t'$ is an integer, so  $l + l'$$\in$n$\cdot$$\mathbb{Z}$.

Next, we show that if $l$ $\in$ n$\cdot$$\mathbb{Z}$, $-l$$\in$n$\mathbb{Z}$:

Since $l$=n$\cdot$$t$ for some integer $t$, we have $-l$=-(n$t$)=n($-t$), and since $-t$ is also an integer, $-l$$\in$n$\cdot$$\mathbb{Z}$.

Can anyone correct me please!!!

Comment: You're almost there: no just show the set $\,n\Bbb Z\,$ isn't empty...

Comment: ohh ok!!! thankx alot @DonAntonio

Comment: LaTeX should be used properly. Why should write n$\mathbb Z$ and not $n\mathbb Z$? (All mathematical symbols are usually between two $.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're work is fine.

*Now you need only show that your group contains the identity* of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is, of course, $0$. Can you find a $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\cdot k = 0$? (When $k = 0, n\cdot 0 = 0$. Since $k = 0 \in \mathbb{Z},\, 0 \in n\mathbb{Z}.$

- Note: If you do this first, you will then have shown that $n\mathbb{Z}$ is not empty, and you can confirm that $l + - l = 0$, so that $-l$ is indeed the inverse of $l \in n\mathbb{Z}$.

This, together with closure under addition and under inverses, which you've shown, is enough to prove that $n\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Z}$: that $n\mathbb{Z}$ is indeed a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is this okay now, Timoci?

Comment: yes amWhy!!! thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome!